# API naming Conventions, same resource noun in the URI

Tags: rest, api, mobile, naming, conventions

I'm working on a project for a mobile device, and trying to keep to an API standard as this will be a an API used by others.
Is it appropriate to use the same resource noun in the same resource URI?

For example, for an API that will check if a particular device should be blacklisted from our service:
**v1.0/device/blacklist/device/**

Is it appropriate to use **device** twice here? I can't seem to find anywhere that mention if this is an appropriate thing to do for API naming conventions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to use device twice here?

Sure, why not?  REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers, so it certainly shouldn't care that some path-segments have common spellings.

For instance, if you were identifying nodes in a binary tree, an identifier like

```
/tree/root/left/left/right/left/...
```

is *fine*.

The machines don't care what spellings you use; so the only question is whether or not it is acceptable to the humans in your context; in other words, see your local design guidelines.